# React component failing to update state

Tags: reactjs

The code I'm talking about can be found in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-volhard-93kfvb?file=/src/App.js).

I'm currently working on a clone of a memory game called Indefinite Interrogation. The way it works is you're asked questions; you have to always answer the same questions with the same answers. The first time you're asked each question, your answer doesn't matter; but every time you're asked that question again, you must answer with whatever you chose the first time.

What's supposed to happen in my code is that `questionList` (the list of questions be asked) gets updated via the `getNextQuestion()` function every 10th question, and the `Game` component is supposed to continue displaying questions. What actually happens is my website crashes after answering the 10th question correctly, because it "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '10')"; the `questionList` logic somehow returns `undefined` (the error occurs on line 512).

I'm not sure why, but state variables such as `currentListIndex` (the current index in questionList) don't seem to be getting updated by `getNextQuestion()`. Even after that function gets called, the old value of `currentListIndex` seems to still be getting used, and that breaks the game every 10 questions (each `questionList` is 10 elements long so the max index is 9; `currentListIndex` seems to become 10 at some point for unknown reasons).

`questionsIndices` (basically an array of indices to determine which `list`s of questions can be used to generate `questionList`) also seems to fail to get updated by that same function.

My only guess is that I'm using `useEffect()` incorrectly. Thank you for taking the time to read this, and I appreciate any assistance I can receive to resolve this issue.

**EDIT**: use the console output to see the `correctAnswer` to each question. Game overs will cause the game to reset itself back to score 0 (this may take a few seconds).

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible in codesandbox. I only get the question reset slowness after 5 questions

Comment: @NickVu the slowness should be from the game over code resetting the game. Use the console to see the ```correctAnswer``` to each question so you can get to 10 questions

Comment: The error originates in `useState(questionList[currentListIndex])`. Try to refactor all of your `useState`s so that they don't depend on each other, like here both `questionList` and `currentListIndex` are themselves results of `useState`.

Comment: @tromgy thank you so much; I managed to fix the bug thanks to your advice. I never knew about the dependent ```useState``` stuff you said to avoid so yeah... lesson learned on my part :)